# How to plot multiple graph in one figure by fetching data from one csv file (matplotlib or panda)

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot graph of internet speed. In graph both downloading and uploading speed should show with time series.

Both speeds and date time have saved to a csv file.  And the file has time, download speed and upload speed in first, second and third column.

I need a graph with time in X axis and both speed in Y axis.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at pandas online documentation :
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html
This would do all you need. Basically as soon as you did your

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv()
```

you just have to use the plot method on it using x and y such as :

```
df.plot(x='col1', y='col2')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me try this